# Plugin for Zooming a map with Panel and mouse control

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, dictionary, zooming

for my work I need a plugin in javascript or jquery that allows me to zoom to an image (a map I created) with the mouse (mouse wheel) and a panel with buttons (+ and -). The plugin should also allow me to move around the map by dragging the image.

Important: This plugin has to be free,because it'll be used on a website.

The image is high quality (takes about 2 mb) so the zoom will be pretty intense (from 10% to 90%).

I've been looking online and none really help me on what I need

I hope answer, thanks to all

**EDIT:**

http://www.jacklmoore.com/wheelzoom/

Something like this but with a panel of buttons to zoom

Comment: Just Google it http://www.jacklmoore.com/wheelzoom/

Comment: That was my first option @AamirAfridi but, it hasn't a panel with buttons to zoom without scrolling :(

Comment: @AamirAfridi Oh! thx, create an answer and i can vote up you :D

Comment: Just found this http://www.doogal.co.uk/zoomable.php :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the plugin a little bit. check this out http://bit.ly/1mUSAfE the problem is that once you click the zoom in or out button, the mouse wheel zoom doesn't work properly unless you zoom out completely and than zoom in.

I am still working on fixing it. I will comment if it works for me :)